# memory leak (Valgrind) on a grid of points

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm creating a map grid (a 2D discrete number of points) using the concept of mapPixel, a class:

```
class MapPixel
{
    friend class Map;
protected:
    int x;
    int y;
    float height;
    float vegetation;

    std::vector<const MapPixel*> neib;
...methods declaration, default constructor/destructor
```

where neib is a list of pointers to other MapPixels, adjacent to then.

I'm using the method

```
void MapPixel::addNeib(const MapPixel* neib_)
{
    neib.push_back(neib_);
}
```

to add a pointer to a neiber pixel to build the graph (since the borders have less neibs than the center pixels, this list is size dependent).

My procedure is to have a class Map with a member

```
MapPixel **pixels;
```

in the constructor Map::Map() using

```
pixels = new MapPixel*[width];
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    pixels[i] = new MapPixel[height];
```

I use the method MapPixel::addNode() to build the network (e.g.)

```
pixels[i][j].addNeib(&pixels[i][j+1]);
```

and in the Map::~Map() I delete MapPixel by the inverse order (without deleting the neibs to avoid double free):

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    delete pixels[i];
delete pixels;
```

Valgrind says there are several big memory leaks like this:

```
2,509,088 bytes in 39,205 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 4,071 of 4,071
  in MapPixel::addNeib(MapPixel const*) in Source/mappixel.cpp:52
  1: malloc in vg_replace_malloc.c:266
  2: operator new(unsigned long) in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib
  3: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator&lt;MapPixel const*&gt;::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) in ...
  4: std::_Vector_base&lt;MapPixel const*, std::allocator&lt;MapPixel const*&gt; &gt;::_M_allocate(unsigned long) in stl_vector.h:131
  5: std::vector&lt;MapPixel const*, std::allocator&lt;MapPixel const*&gt; &gt;::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator&lt;MapPixel const**, std::vector&lt;MapPixel const*, std::allocator&lt;MapPixel const*&gt; &gt; &gt;, MapPixel const* const&amp;) in vector.tcc:271
  6: std::vector&lt;MapPixel const*, std::allocator&lt;MapPixel const*&gt; &gt;::push_back(MapPixel const* const&amp;) in stl_vector.h:608
  7: MapPixel::addNeib(MapPixel const*) in mappixel.cpp:52
```

all related to the line 52:

```
neib.push_back(neib_);
```

Does anyone understands this? Now I lost confidence on if I can use std::vector to build the neibs of my pixels.

Comment: in a possible problem of memory leak, you should give us both how you alloc (new) and how you dealloc (delete)... here a part is missing. E.g. you delete MaxPixel in reverse order, ok; but do you the pixels itself? I suppose the answer is yes, and that the given answer applies. Though, it would have been better to have the  full new/delete code to look at!

Comment: added the delete code. I'm saying is not because of that because Valgrind does not complain about with the new pixels/new pixels[i], that why I assumed the problem was not there.

Comment: shouldn't be `delete[]` instead?

Comment: I'm rusty at C++, my doubt was if `delete[]` invokes destructors over the elements, and it does, but here we have plain pointers, not MapPixel objects or references to them, so it seems that: you free your dinamically created MapPixel objects, but not correctly the dinamically created array of pointers (to such objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that valgrind said "*possibly* lost", not "*definitely* lost".  The difference is important.  See [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.deflost) for the exact meanings.

That error is about blocks allocated by the `vector<>` implementation code, most likely to resize the block of memory containing the elements as the `vector` grows.  You might get these if you are allocating instances of `MapPixel` and forgetting to free them, since the containing `vector` would then not be able to free its memory, but then you would also get errors about your own code.

Unless! when you free the `pixels` arrays, are you using `delete[]` or `delete`?

Update: you're using `delete`.  You need to use `delete[]`.  This is indeed a memory leak.  Anything you allocate with `new[]` must be freed with `delete[]`, otherwise the proper destructor (even one automatically generated by the compiler) will only be called for the first element.

Comment: +1 for question about pixels... just finished commenting about lack of details ... :)

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer already mentioned, the memory leak is most likely caused by the wrong `delete` operator. In the constructor you create an array of arrays using [operator new[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20new%5B%5D/):

```
pixels = new MapPixel*[width];
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
  pixels[i] = new MapPixel[height];
```

You need to free the memory for the arrays using the corresponding array-delete [operator delete[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20delete%5B%5D/):

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
  delete [] pixels[i];
delete [] pixels;
```

However, I would suggest you to use a nested `std::vector` for your pixel matrix instead. This way you get memory management for free.

```
std::vector<std::vector<MapPixel> > pixels;
// in constructor something like:
pixels.resize(width, std::vector<MapPixel>(height));
// nothing to do in destructor
```

For your neighbors, I wouldn't use a std::vector, but a plain `MapPixel *neib[8];` (assuming Moore Neighborhood) or rather `std::array<MapPixel*, 8> neib;`. But I don't know what other requirements you might have on this item.

Besides the memory management, using the STL containers gives you other benefits as well, e.g., handy member functions, they don't decay to pointers, just to name a few.

Comment: "(since the borders have less neibs than the center pixels, this list is size dependent)" That's why I didn't used MapPixel *neib[8]. Besides, allocation is only in the beginning, once allocated, std::vector is constant access. About the answer, I will check to see if it fixes the error.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão nah you gain some [locality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference), i.e. the memory for the array is directly integrated in the object itself, whereas the memory for the vector elements resides elsewhere on the heap. But considering such things is probably more like premature-optimization.

Comment: With 2,509,088 bytes probably lost I think is premature to add entropy to the code... xD